# Jquery datetimepicker buffer issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have used jQuery date/time picker for both the start date and the end date.
After selecting start date we are having some buffer according to the time needed for creating some booking.
So when we click on end date picker and click on some particular date it took the current time even if it is less then the start time.
But after getting click somewhere else in the window when we click again on the same date in the end date/time picker it picks up the exact date with the buffer.
So i want to know that how can i get the exact result in the very first time in end datetimepicker with the buffer ?

code:

```
////////////// Intialize start date and time /////////////////////////////
var mindate = moment().add("30", "minutes")
jQuery('#startDate').datetimepicker({

    minDateTime: new Date(mindate),
    minDate: new Date(mindate),
    // defaultDate:new Date($scope.data.startDate),
    defaultTime: new Date(mindate),
    step: 5,
    format: "m/d/Y h:i A",
    minTime: '08:00 am',
    maxTime: '10:00 pm',
    onShow: function () {
        if (jQuery('#endDate').val()) {
            jQuery('#endDate').val('')
        }
    }
})
$scope.startttt = $('#startDate').val();
console.log("start value", $scope.startttt);


////////////// Intialize end date and time /////////////////////////////

$scope.getEndDate = function () {
    $scope.timeCount = false;
    jQuery('#endDate').datetimepicker({
        onShow: function () {
            if ($scope.massageFor != "Me + 1 : Together") {
                var durationTotal = parseInt($scope.data.duration) + parseInt($scope.data.durationBack);
                var a = moment(jQuery('#startDate').val()).add(durationTotal, "minutes");
                if (a) {
                    this.setOptions({
                        minDate: new Date(a),
                        minDateTime: new Date(a),
                        startDate: new Date(a),
                        defaultDate: new Date(a),
                        // defaultTime:new Date(a),
                        step: 5,
                        format: "m/d/Y h:i A"
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                var durationTotal = parseInt($scope.data.duration) + parseInt($scope.data.duration);
                var a = moment(jQuery('#startDate').val()).add(durationTotal, "minutes");
                if (a) {
                    this.setOptions({
                        minDate: new Date(a),
                        minDateTime: new Date(a),
                        startDate: new Date(a),
                        defaultDate: new Date(a),
                        // defaultTime:new Date(a),
                        step: 5,
                        format: "m/d/Y h:i A"
                    })
                }
            }
        }

    })
}`
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why is angularjs also tagged? Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually the project is in angularjs
Just used jquery datetimepicker only